# Silent Install Shockwave 12.3.4 Without Norton Utilties Popup

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I am attempting to silently install Adobe Shockwave 12.3.4 using the Slim `shockwave.exe`(have used the full install exe as well) using PowerShell, eventually deploying it through SCCM once finished.

Right now, I am having an issue where I continue getting a prompt asking to get Norton Security Scan for free and I do not want this prompt to show up at all during the installation.

Here is the prompt. I am open to any ideas on how to avoid this.

Here is the Powershell Script:

```
$currentpath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$run = 1

#Disable Norton on Install This was used on Adobe Digital Editions to stop a 
norton pop-up, but does not help us here

New-Item 
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\N360' 
-Force

do {
   if (Get-Process "iexplore" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object 
   {-not $_.HasExited }) {
     Write-host "quitting"
     Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
     $run++
   }
else {
    # Run install and copy config file for updates/settings
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList 
    "/i""$($currentpath)\sw_lic_full_installer.msi""/qn" -Wait -PassThru
    Start-sleep -Seconds 60
    $run=26
    }
} While ($run -le 25)
```

[image: Norton Prompt]

Comment: Are you able to include the PowerShell script you are using?

Comment: Script has been added

Comment: Did you download the latest MSI from `https://www.adobe.com/products/shockwaveplayer/distribution3.html`? I'm not getting the prompt with the MSI, and I'm getting a chrome prompt instead of a Norton one on the slim exe

Comment: Was trying to find the MSI for awhile with no luck, so this is definitely a great find.  Thank you.